# PHPMailer: Set custom header to identify it inside the bounce email

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, email-bounces

I'm sending emails with PHPMailer. When an email is bounced it goes to an account like this: account_bounces@domain.com

Inside my email client where I manage this account (account_bounces@domain.com), I have the option to adds filters in order to redirect an email to any other email account, based on the comparation of fields like "Subject", "From", "To" and so on. That's good.

The problem is that the bounced email loses all of my headers/Subject...that I set with PHPMailer because it's **ALWAYS** composed by the server as it follows:

- Subject: Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender
- From: MAILER-DAEMON@llsd409-a04.servidoresdns.net
- To:   account_bounces@domain.com
- Date: Today hh:mm

So I have no guide marks to use for adding a filter.

So, is there any way to set a mark(like a custom header, etc...) in PHPMailer that **REMAINS** in the bounced email?. For example, something like having this:

- Subject: Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender (bounce_redirect)

So the word "bounce_redirect" in the Subject(or wherever) would indicate my email client that this email has to be redirected.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way you can force this issue in headers; The only way around it is to use [VERP addressing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_envelope_return_path), which is the only way that you can guarantee that it preserves info about the message and what address it was originally sent to. It's common for MS Exchange to send bounce messages that do not mention the original address the message was sent to at all, so VERP is the only solution.

For your example, a typical VERP address would be:

```
account_bounces-user=domain.com@domain.com
```

You mail server would be set to spot the `account_bounces` prefix and remove it, and convert the `=` to a `@` in the local part to extract the original address.

In PHPMailer you would set this as your `Sender` property, like:

```
$mail->Sender = 'account_bounces-user=domain.com@domain.com';
```

This will be used as the SMTP envelope sender, and converted to a `Return-Path`
header by the receiving server, and thus will be used as the `RCPT TO` address (the bounce destination) when the message gets bounced.

You can take this further and embed additional info in the `Sender` address that can be used to identify the mailing list, a specific mailshot etc.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot Synchro!, you saved may day. I was so lost. But you took me to the right place. I made a little modification and it worked (I used "+" instead of "-"). Just as follows: $mail->Sender = 'account_bounces+user=domain.com@domain.com';

Comment: I tried using `$mail->Sender = 'account_bounces-user=bounce@mydomain.com;` but for some reason I doesn't receive the bouced email, but if I do: `$mail->Sender = 'bounce@mydomain.com;` I receive it.. how can I fix?

Comment: You can't just set it and have it work – you need to configure your mail server to spot inbound addresses using that pattern too and route them to the right inbox at your end, as described in [the postfix VERP docs](http://www.postfix.org/VERP_README.html)